# Float number is displayed as phone number for Opera-mobile

Tags: number-formatting, opera-mobile

I'm developing small web-mobile application. Some my page contains float number. But on Opera-mobile this number is displayed as link to deal phone number. I have found similar issue for Safari:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
```

But this doesn't works for Opera-mobile. How to to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Although likely not the best solution you can use javascript to find the `<a href="tel..."` blocks and remove the href attribute from there.

Comment: well, it is good idea if JScript is allowed (Opera Mini 4 for example).